# My script works on Windows but doesn't work on Linux-About Folder Path

Tags: python, linux, windows, filepath

I wrote a script.It is getting a file modify time from a Windows Server. It is working on Windows but not on Linux. It means there is a file on Windows Server and I want to get this file's modify time from Linux. I tried backslashes, double slashes and pathlib library but not working. Here is my Linux output.

```
[root@server03]# python3 serveropen2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serveropen2.py", line 5, in <module>
    modify = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(server))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\Server1\tools\folder\capture.JPG'
```

Here is my codes

```
    import os
    import datetime as dt

    server=r'\\Server1\tools\folder\capture.JPG'
    modify = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(server))

    if dt.datetime.now() - modify > dt.timedelta(minutes=5):
        print("old")
    else:
        print("new")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the currect path separator. Under windows \ is the separator, under linux / is the separator.

So instead of

`\\Server1\tools\folder\capture.JPG'`

your script has to use

`/Server1/tools/folder/capture.JPG'`

By using **os.path.join** you can fix this:

```
import os
server = os.path.join('Server1', 'tools', 'folder', 'capture.JPG')
...
```

And you need to know where the file is located in your filesystem on linux. If it is located somewhere in your home-directory you can do something like:

```
import os

my_server_dir = os.path.join('~', 'server_home')
server = os.path.join('Server1', 'tools', 'folder', 'capture.JPG')
...
```

Comment: That alone won’t accomplish anything. It’s a UNC path, which can be accessed transparently on Windows. It’ll have to be manually mounted on other OSes.

Comment: Shall be more clarified. Thanks for your feedback!